# Converting a list into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

This is the list I have and I want to convert it into a dictionary for key values 1-9. I'm using benford's law and I'm trying to find the starting digit of each number and keep track of how many times each number is the starting number. Here's my list. It goes on much longer but i only copied a small amount.

```
['2930', '4782', '709', '433', '29861', '20115', '15114', '2417', '737', '966', '8863', '355', '23561', '8272', '1288', '1961', '746', '318', '2100', '1890', '2643', '24194', '10109', '6587', '57828', '877', '488', '624', '722', '322', '222', '8342', '3163',......
```

Comment: What are you trying to count?

Comment: For the values do you want the number of numbers that begin with digit `i` or do you want the numbers themselves?

Answer (score 9):

```
from collections import Counter
l = ['2930', '4782', '709', '433', '29861', '20115', '15114', '2417', '737', '966', '8863', '355', '23561', '8272', '1288', '1961', '746', '318', '2100', '1890', '2643', '24194', '10109', '6587', '57828', '877', '488', '624', '722', '322', '222', '8342', '3163']
c = Counter(x[0] for x in l)


>>> c
Counter({'2': 9, '1': 5, '3': 4, '7': 4, '8': 4, '4': 3, '6': 2, '5': 1, '9': 1})
```

Comment: BTW you don't need a list comprehension, a generator expression is much more memory friendly (especially as the OP said their list is much longer), so you can drop the `[]`